$Gl_n(F)$ representation over $M_{n \times n}(F)$
Suppose representation $\rho$ of $Gl_n(F)$ over $M_{n \times n}(F)$ by $\rho(A)X = AXA^{-1}$, $\mathbb{char} (F)$ doesn't divide $n$. The task it to prove it can be decombosed into direct sum of irreducible representations. I can see two invariant subspaces: denote $V = \{X \in M_{n \times n}(F)| \mathbb{tr}(X) = 0 \}$ and $W = \mathbb{span}(E)$. Clearly, $M_{n \times n}(F) = V \bigoplus W$ and W is irreducible, but how do I know that for $V$?
